scenePhase does not return any phase after adding widget extension in Swift App Project
I am trying to detect app's life cycle in my app project.
When I try with scenePhase method or UIApplication,
it will give right feedback when starting app or moving to background.
But after I add a widget extension in a swift project, the above methods didn't work as expect.
It will not print anything when I change the status of app.
With these code, when I start app in simulator, it will print >> your code is here on scene become active.
When I go to home,
it will print  ">> your code is here on scene become inactive" and ">> your code is here on scene go background"
After adding widget extension with live activity, nothing will be printed when I start or leave app.
import SwiftUI

@main
struct notificationCenter_testApp: App {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase)var scenePhase
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
                    switch phase {
                    case .active:
                        print(">> your code is here on scene become active")
                    case .inactive:
                        print(">> your code is here on scene become inactive")
                    case .background:
                        print(">> your code is here on scene go background")
                    default:
                        print(">> do something else in future")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

import SwiftUI

@main
struct StoneYourPhone_1App: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification)) { _ in
                            print("App did become active")
                        }
                .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification)) { _ in

                            print("In Background")
                        }
        }
        .modelContainer(for: NoteClass.self)
    }
}

